# How custom animations work in Minecraft using Trainguys-Animation-Overhaul as an example?

Tags: minecraft

This mod's repository uses JSON files to describe the character's animation frames. The `rotation` attribute is responsible for the rotation of the character's body part, and the rotation is specified in radians. And the `translate` attribute is an offset by the number of specified game units.

However, the size of these game units is not quite clear to me. Is 1 the size corresponding to the width of the block? Also, where are the origins of each body part of the player model? From which point is the rotation and offset calculated?

JSON file example:

```
"format_version":"0.2",
"frame_length":20,
"parts":[
    ...
    {
    "name": "leftLeg",
    "keyframes": {
        "0": {
            "translate": [
                0.252,
                -0.543,
                -3.344
            ],
            "rotate": [
                -0.5905,
                0.0,
                0.02526
            ]
        },
        "1": {
            "translate": [
                0.121,
                0.406,
                -3.377
            ],
            "rotate": [
                -0.57598,
                -0.0,
                0.01201
            ]
        }
    }
}
...
```